# How can I run python script involving sklearn (k-means) as the backend of my project without the need of using pickle or similar?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, scikit-learn, backend, knn

I am currently trying to develop a simple chrome extension for a project that requires passing some text data from the browser (JS frontend) to a backend consisting of a python script, apply clustering and return the clusters + labels. I have tried with AWS Lambda but I have had no success importing sklearn through a layer. All the resources I consult seem to be using pickle or similar to deploy their models, but I do not think I can do that since I need the clusters to be determined automatically. I would basically need a way to run similar code to the one below every time is requested from the extension:

```
    # receive data from JS via Post request

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

    # Create a vectorizer to convert text data into numerical vectors
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
    
    # Initialize K-means clustering algorithm
    kmeans = KMeans()
    
    # Set the range of number of clusters to consider
    min_clusters = len(data) // 6
    max_clusters = len(data) // 3

    # Initialize variables to store the best number of clusters and its inertia
    best_clusters = -1
    best_inertia = float('inf')

    # Get the cluster labels for the data points
    cluster_labels = kmeans.labels_
```

Will any of these platforms help me achieve my purpose?: Heroku, Replit, Digital Ocean, Azure.

Comment: what is `data` in this context ? or what are you expecting for `data` ?

Comment: It would be some text data extracted from the tabs. Mainly titles and url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want deploy models,serverless service like lambda is not always the best option because the cold start will impact you user experience.
I recommend you use containers and try AWS ECS Service with Fargate, and if you still want to use serverless service, you could choose run your container directly on a ECS task.

https://youtu.be/-Vsuzi4OByY

Comment: Thanks, I am looking into it. My questions is, my approach wouldn´t be such as deploying a model (like training it and applying to new data, in a serialized way like pickle or joblib. I would just want to execute similar steps to the ones in my code, and I don´t think that can be achieved by saving the model (especially with the step included to set the ideal number of clusters automatically9. I would be ideally looking for a way to perform those steps every time I send some text from the frontend.